# Angular scrollbar percentage

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scroll, scrollbar, percentage

I need to find the percantage of the scroll-bar in angular.js. Then, when it reaches about 60% to call a function. Right now I am using a scope function which is called from the directive, the only problem is I cannot find on how many percent is the scrollbar scrolled down. This is what I have so far, does not look too good...

```
app.directive('whenScrolled', function($window) {

return function(scope, element, attr) {
    var scrolledEl = angular.element($window);

    angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function() {

    var offSet = scrolledEl.offset(),
        height = scrolledEl.height(),
        scrolledPercentage = (offSet / height)*11;

        if (scrolledPercentage >= 60) {
          scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
        }
    });
};
```

});

As you can see I found experimentally that when I multiply this by 11 I get the percentage, but it works only in a few screen heights. I need a generall solution and later, when I append more elements to the dom and the body extends to give me a correct %. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `$window.pageYOffset` and  `$window.innerHeight` 
Their division will give you a value from 0 to 1 so if you prefer a comparison to a percentage kind of number, just multiply by 100.

This should work like you want, more or less (just replace console.log with whatever action you need to take if the percentage is > 60):

```
  angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function() {

    var offSet = $window.pageYOffset,
        height = $window.innerHeight,
        scrolledPercentage = (offSet / height * 100);
        //console.log(scrolledPercentage);
        if (scrolledPercentage >= 60) {
          console.log(scrolledPercentage + ' over 60');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, I really believed it will work, but not really. After more elements are appended it starts calling the function on maybe 5% scroll ;( Any other ideas?

Comment: In the context of your question and the code you provided, this works as it should. If there are other things happening you should describe in more detail or make a different question.

Comment: Well, as I said, I am appending elements dynamically to the dom, therefore I need an always-upgrading percentage of how much the page is scrolled - like how much distance the scrollbar travelled from top to bottom (visually). When I log this it works fine at the beginning (well not really, about 117% max) and than I go to about 3000%, which is, of course, not real. I am trying to do something like the dynamic-scroll-query in facebook - when we reach about 60%, more posts are dynamically loaded

Comment: You are describing a different situation, imho you should take it from here and ask a new question, providing more code and details. Again, your question was answered.

Comment: Whatever man... IMPORTANT: if anyone else is troubled with this, here is the solution I found myself: [ng-infinite-scroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) Pretty much gives you the availability to call a function when certain scroll-percentage is reached and waits untill the function is done (via scroll-disabled - read documentation). It works great with remote data querying :)

Comment: Sadly that link you provided is not dead :c